# Append text string after first character in textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea, append, character

I have what seems like a very simple task but can't wrap my head around it.  Is there a way to append a text string after the first character in a "textarea" html element?

I have some code below to start off.

Script:

```
    $.each(results, function (i, marker) {
    $("#geofenceCoords").append('{"latitude":' + marker.position.lat() + ', ' + '"longitude":' + marker.position.lng() + '},' + '<br>');
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <textarea id="geofenceCoords" name="geofenceCoords"style="height:90px; width:450px; font-size:12px;">[]</textarea>
```

I basically want to append the text after the first bracket inside the "textarea."  Any Ideas?

Comment: what do you expect? `[these would be coordinates] + <br>` ???

Comment: Why dont't you remove the brackets and call $("#geofenceCoords").append('[these would be coordinates' + '<br>]');

Comment: I guess I didn't explain in my question.  I have a $.each loop grabbing coordinates and appending that script above.  So if I included the brackets in the string it would put brackets around each coordinate string.  I would like to wrap all coordinates around the brackets as they get appended.

Comment: I have edited my code to represent the problem more clear.  If I append the string with the brackets now, the brackets will be around each coordinate, which wouldn't be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
$(function(){
    var items = '';
    $.each(results, function (i, marker) {
        items+= '  {latitude:'  + marker.position.lat() + ', ' + 'longitude:' + marker.position.lng() +'},\n';
    });
    $("#geofenceCoords").val('['+'\n'+items.substr(0, (items.length-2))+'\n]');
});
```

This will output something like this

```
[
  {latitude:123, longitude:321},
  {latitude:567, longitude:765}
]
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you sir for your quick reply.  I totally forgot about substr().  This worked perfectly for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Create the final string you want to add and then wrap it with your `[` `]`:

```
$.each(results, function (i, marker) {
    myCoordenates = myCoordenates + i + '<br>';
});

$("#geofenceCoords").empty();
$("#geofenceCoords").append('[' + myCoordenates  +  ']');
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/qAfCM/

Comment: This would have worked if I had a set array. But unfortunately my markers(coordinates) were being created dynamically.